# Does PowerShell have an Infinity value

Tags: powershell

Does PowerShell have a variable or value for infinity?

Perhaps similar to the $null variable?

I have tried $inifinity.  I have also tried 1/0 to generate the value.

Comment: like `[double]::PositiveInfinity`?

Comment: Like that @mikez, is there one for Int32?

Comment: For integral types there is no "infinity" value.

Comment: cool, thanks @mikez, if you make this an answer I will accept.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is `[double]::PositiveInfinity`. I suspect if you used `1.0/0.0` you would get this value. `1/0` should produce an error, as there is no infinity value for any of the integral types.

Comment: 1.0/0.0 does produce Infinity.  Thanks!

Comment: And don't forget about `[double]::NegativeInfinity`.