# NaN or Exception?

Tags: python, powershell, exception, nan, ieee-754

In Python, taking a square root of a negative number throws an exception.
In PowerShell, it returns a `NaN`.

Why the difference? I believe, according to IEEE 754, the PowerShell behavior is the correct one. Is that so? At least, that is the idea I got from [the article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

And I believe that a division by zero should produce a `NaN` as well, but both Python and PowerShell throw exceptions in this case.

Comment: different languages behave differently?

Comment: But shouldn't they conform to the same standard, namely IEEE 754, for arithmetic?

Comment: Careful with the division in PowerShell/.NET. Integer division by zero throws, but double division returns +/- infinity for +/- 1.0/0.0 and NaN for 0.0/0.0. I believe that is somewhat normal. The IEEE 754 standard is for floating point arithmetic not integer arithmetic.

Comment: You could catch an exception in Python using except using `try` and `except`.  Under the exception, use `float('NaN')` to get `NaN`.  Languages differ between each other (including modules such as numpy), so you'll have to adapt your code accordingly.

Comment: From the same article, _"So the IEEE standard defines c/0 == ±Inf, as long as c != 0."_ So again, the PowerShell/.NET are closer to the standard than Python, it would seem.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer to the question-**

[image: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html]

As you can see, division by zero does not always produce a NaN. The exceptions, on the other hand, are possibly generated as **infinity** might not have been defined as a **special-quantity** in both Python and PowerShell.

**Note on special-quantity-**

> Without any special quantities, there is no good way to handle exceptional situations like taking the square root of a negative number, other than aborting computation.

(**Source:** https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

**From** https://stackoverflow.com/a/26870777/3681882-
It is clear that for PowerShell, no **infinity** value for any of the integral types exists.

Comment: Both PowerShell and Python seem to have Infinity defined, as well as NaN.

Comment: @coding4fun I believe there is a difference between having `infinity` defined and returning an `infinity`, although more research has to be done on this. Have you found any official documentation for Python or PowerShell that claims a strict adherence to IEEE 754??

Comment: Yes, it says that PowerShell has positive and negative infinity, same as IEEE 754.

Comment: @coding4fun For floating-point values, not integers. What have you tried??

Comment: No, I have not found any claims to IEEE 754 adherence.

Comment: that might explain the ambiguous behaviour

Comment: In IEEE754, division by 0 produces plus or minus infinity.  NaN is produced by expressions that would be "indeterminate" in calculus, like infinity minus infinity or zero divided by zero.  I don't recall if IEEE754 defines anything for the square root of a negative number.  I don't see why it would.  That's a plain error.  (Unless it's caused by rounding near 0, and then the right answer would be 0.)